# Pass output from module to another provider in Terrafrom

Tags: terraform

In TF, I try to pass the output from a module to a provider in the same main.tf. `Terrafrom init` runs first and It won't accept this. Do we have any way to pass this?

I'm using the latest TF version.

Comment: No, this is not possible in a declarative DSL. If you share the relevant code, then we could assist with removing the module output dependency from the provider.

Comment: Thanks, if I separate it into 2 folders, can I use a command like "terraform apply -target=module.user-key"